# I accidently deleted folders available under \Local\Android\Sdk. Now getting couldn't found adb.exe while running App Automation using Appium

Tags: automation, appium, adb

I am new to Appium mobile app Automation. I accidently deleted folders under \Users\Jayesh Prajapati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.

Now when I try to run scenarios, It is giving me error `Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'adb.exe`

Comment: adb is part of the platform-tools which are available here for download: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: Thanks @Robert. Resolved this issue.